# Open Office Formula: Calculate Positive & Negative Numbers in Same Column

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'd like to perform the following calculation (in Open Office Calc or Excel) and would like to know the formula for doing so:

Take a number (in currency format) in one column, and increase or decrease it by a percentage from a second column (percentage will be a positive or a negative number) and generate the correct result in a third column.

Examples:

1) If $1.00 is increased by 25% the correct result is: $1.25. 
2) If $5.00 is decreased by 50% the correct result is: $2.50.

It seems to me I need to use some kind of conditional formula, which says: "If the percentage is less than zero, subtract it from the currency number. If the percentage is greater than zero, add it to the currency number."

Am I correct? If so, what would the correct formula be, for Open Office or Excel? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google "excel conditional formula"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your concept is correct.  Here is a formula that works on open office

```
5   50  7.5     =A2+(B2/100)*A2
```

10  -50 5       =A3+(B3/100)*A3
15  -33 10.05   =A4+(B4/100)*A4

Column A has value, Column B % , Column C result,  Column D shows formula behind column C

Answer (score 0):

Well, the basic formula is `amt * (1 + percentage/100)`. For `amt=1` and `percentage=25`, that gives 1.25; for `amt=5` and `percentage=-50` it gives 2.5. You may need to reformat the formula for your particular program.

Another way to write the formula is `amt + amt*(percentage/100)`. That demonstrates a little more clearly what's happening: for negative percentages, you're adding a negative number to `amt`, which is to say making `amt` smaller.

Comment: If anyone could provide the proper formula for Open Office or Excel (preferably Open Office), it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much Sneftel - your response was fast!